# How to define meta tags for each container in single html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For now I am concerned regarding any way or approach to define meta tags for each container in one single html file.
I will explain in more details.

We created web site, which is literally consist of one single-page (all sub pages are inside this long scrolling page).
So, when you navigate through the link in left menu, first page will be scrolled down to the second page and so on....

But, if we will take into account SEO optimization of this web resource, single-page site has to be turn one page site into a multi-page site.
So, my question, how should we define meta tags for each container (sub page) in one single html?

Example of website with the same thing (one long scrolling page with all sub pages inside itself):http://lovepublic.com.au/

Hope, that anybody can help with this issue somehow and advice good option.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any possibility.
As defined on [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp):
`<meta>` tags always goes inside the `<head>` element.

You can however **improve** your website in other ways:

- Have one `h1` heading for the website
- Use the `h2` heading for categorizing your page (per container)
- And the `h3` for sub categorizing each container

Simply doing this already improves the website SEO wise. Search engine spiders actually check the relevancy of the header tag with the content associated with it.

You might also check into **Microdata** to ensure search engines know what you are talking about. Go to http://schema.org/docs/gs.html for more info